# How to use C# export QTP result to PDF automatically

Tags: c#, .net, qtp, hp-uft

I'm writing a C# program to run QTP.

Now my program can trigger QTP automatically and send the result to my mailbox. But this result is HTML, i find that QTP can export a PDF result.

so, here is my code.

```
qtpAutoReport = qtpApp.Options.Run.AutoExportReportConfig;
qtpAutoReport.AutoExportResults = true;
qtpAutoReport.StepDetailsReport = true;
qtpAutoReport.DataTableReport = false;
qtpAutoReport.LogTrackingReport = false;
qtpAutoReport.ScreenRecorderReport = false;
qtpAutoReport.SystemMonitorReport = false;
qtpAutoReport.StepDetailsReportFormat = "Short";
qtpAutoReport.ExportLocation = AutoExportPath;
qtpAutoReport.ExportForFailedRunsOnly = false;
qtpAutoReport.StepDetailsReportType = "PDF";
```

When i use this code `qtpAutoReport.StepDetailsReportType = "HTML";`
My program can run successfully, and i can find this HTML file on my disk.

But, when i use this code `qtpAutoReport.StepDetailsReportType = "PDF";` 
After QTP test is over, i can't any file on my disk. 
So my question is why QTP can't export result when i set StepDetailsReportType as "PDF"?

Comment: Really? No one know this? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does seem to be an issue with UFT, I found a method that works for GUI tests(vbscript), give it a try with Service Test (c#).

All options are the same as your example, with one addition:

`uftObject.Options.Run.ViewResults = True`

This tells UFT that you want to view the results after completion. Without this flag I get no PDF result, with it the file is waiting at the export path.

`Option Explicit
Dim uftObject, qtResultsOpt

Set uftObject=CreateObject("Quicktest.application")
uftObject.Launch
uftObject.Visible = True
Set qtResultsOpt = uftObject.Options.Run.AutoExportReportConfig
Dim AutoExportPath
AutoExportPath =  "C:\Users\paxic\Desktop\stackoverflow\results"
qtResultsOpt.AutoExportResults = true
qtResultsOpt.StepDetailsReport = true
qtResultsOpt.DataTableReport = false
qtResultsOpt.LogTrackingReport = false
qtResultsOpt.ScreenRecorderReport = false
qtResultsOpt.SystemMonitorReport = false
qtResultsOpt.StepDetailsReportFormat = "Short"
qtResultsOpt.ExportLocation = AutoExportPath
qtResultsOpt.ExportForFailedRunsOnly = false
qtResultsOpt.StepDetailsReportType = "PDF"
uftObject.Open "C:\Users\JMorley\Desktop\stackoverflow\ExampleOne"
qtResultsOpt.AutoExportResults = True
uftObject.Options.Run.ViewResults = True
uftObject.Test.Run`

Comment: Thx Paxic, i haven't try your solution yet, but i hope your code can help those who facing this problem.